# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation when using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute query using PDO but it throws me an error.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

```
$db = PrestaDB::getInstance($shop->getHost(), $shop->getLogin(), $shop->getPassword(), $shop->getDbName());

$statement = '
    SELECT *
    FROM ps_orders o
    JOIN ps_customer c ON c.id_customer = o.id_customer
    JOIN ps_carrier car ON car.id_carrier = o.id_carrier
    JOIN ps_address a ON o.id_address_delivery = a.id_address
    JOIN ps_address ai ON o.id_address_invoice = ai.id_address
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_customer_thread ct ON ct.id_order = o.id_order
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_customer_message cm ON cm.id_customer_thread = ct.id_customer_thread
    ORDER BY o.date_add DESC
';

if ($result = $db->query($statement)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

When i remove

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_customer_thread ct ON ct.id_order = o.id_order
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_customer_message cm ON cm.id_customer_thread = ct.id_customer_thread
```

from query it works fine. What is wrong with that query?

Comment: There are no syntax errors in this query.

Comment: Do you think anyone would be able to help you without being able to see the structure of the tables?

Comment: DB structure is available here: http://doc.prestashop.com/download/attachments/21463263/mpd16.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1411047693000&api=v2